# How to upload image from raspberry pi to wamp server (web server) automatically?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a camera attached to raspberry pi which captures the image and image saved in raspberry pi memory. I want that image to upload to wamp web server automatically, so I can get it to my android phone.
Thanks

Comment: Better to use NFS file system

Answer (score 1):

Well, in principle you would need an API on the server which you call from the Pi where you send the image to. That should receive the image and handle the storing at the server. 
At the Pi you will have to run some kind of script calling that API. You can trigger that by the a newly captured image available, or e.g. a cron job, just what fits better.
But depending on what you actually want to achieve - just transferring the image(s) to a webdrive - perhaps using e.g. a "network drive approach" perhaps is easier.

Comment: can you tell me that specific API and script that will be used to upload the picture on the apache server.

Comment: Btw me project is smart automatic door locking system in which image is captured at the doorstep by raspberry pi and i want that image to be shown in my android application. kindly suggest me that the above approach to get the image (by web server) is good or not? or i can do somthing else for it? Thanks alot

Comment: well, the API would be something you write by yourself, depending on your actual need. Something common would be a php script receiving a POST for getting the data. So, you could probalbly go with this to develop the script: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Overall, the way you transport and receive the data would be very depending from what you actually want to achieve. From your comment I expect that the transfer shall be happening when someone rings a door bell (or similar event), so more generally spoken from a sudden event. In this case your approach would be suitable, your server should then create a push notification via services provided by google to notify your APP on that event. Anyway, it could be easier to send an email from the pi, but that will not have the push notification. Again, depends on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in few steps:

1>>Setup Apache web server

2>>Setup [vsftpd] or similar FTP deamon on same machine. Please be sure that FTP server upload folder is Apache server root folder. For example [/var/www/html]

3>>Make small script [/home/myname/transfer_files.sh], based on [curl] which will transfer created files to Apache web server via ftp.

```
curl ftp://myftpsite.com --user myname:mypassword
```

4>>Add line in contab [/etc/crontab] which will be executed every single minute

```
*/1   *   *   *   *     root    /home/myname/transfer_files.sh
```

This is not perfect solution, but it will work and you do not need to do any codding.